# Algorithm / pattern to process variable embedded loops in java without recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, recursion

I am looking for an algorithm/pattern to process undefined quantity of inner loops **without recursion**, in java.

I suppose inner loops do the same (or similar) process.

Each loop produces/processes/stores datas, depending on outer loops. So complexity is probably exponential.

Usage: combinatorics for example. But I am looking for a generic solution.

**Some examples (which dont comply):**

**Embedded but not variable**: If the number of inner loops is **known**:

```
for (int i=0;...)
{
// process 1

    for (int j=0;...)
        {
    // process 2

        for (int k=0;...)
            {
            // process 3

            }
        }
}
```

Multiple loops, but **not embedded**

```
for (int which_loop = 1; ...)
{
// LOOP which_loop

// Problem: loops are not embedded, then you cant reuse datas ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach will be to make your iterators actually an array of iterators, and use it to count.

For simplicity, let us assume all variables go up to the same number (`n`), and number of such variables is `num_dimensions`. This assumption can be easily relaxed by checking against another array instead of the value `n`.

Pseudo code:

```
int[] arr = new int[num_dimensions];
int k = 0;
while (true) { 
  if (arr[k] == n) {  // go to next iterator
    k++;
    if (k > num_dimensions - 1) { // done!
      break;
    }
  } 
    if (k == 0) {
      process(arr); // do the process here. arr is the state of the iterators.
      arr[k]++;
    } else { 
      // increase the iterator and go back to the first iterator.
      for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) arr[i] = 0; 
      arr[k]++;
      k = 0;
    }


}
```

The idea is similar to counting with a binary represented number, but the count can go to number `n` - which is not 1:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

Comment: approach is interesting (I used it once for your case !). Do you think it is the only one (or every else is equivalent) ?  I'm not sure of your algorithm : you dont increment or decrement k.